# Ошибка при сохранении результатов парсинга в файл

Tags: python, парсер

Есть парсер:

```
import ssl
import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bss

url = 'sitename'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'}
def get_html(url,params=None):
    r = requests.get(url,headers=headers,params=params)

    return r

def parse():
    html = get_html(url)
    return str(html.text)

print(parse())

with open("file.html", "w", "UTF-8") as f:
    f.write(parse())
```

И есть ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\dlypr\Desktop\main.py", line 29, in <module>
    with open("file.html", "w", "UTF-8") as f:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Не очень понимаю, почему он просит какое-то число. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [документации по команде `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) можно понять, что третьим аргументом принимается не кодировка, а параметр `buffering`, который принимает число (`int`), а вы дали ему строку. Поэтому для кодировки проще указать нужный вам параметр сразу

**Проблема в этой строке**

```
with open("file.html", "w", "UTF-8") as f:
```

Вы указываете кодировку, но делаете это неявно

**Правильно будет так**

```
with open("file.html", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
```